# Update panel does not work after calling the function loginByFacebook()

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using **Facebook Graph JSON responses** in my code to deserialize the JSON string.

I created the class as follow.

```
     <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>


            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
           <div id="fb-root"></div>   
        <a href="#" onclick="loginByFacebook();">Login with Facebook</a>

                    <br /> <br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>

            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
                FB.init({ appId: '<%= ecommerce.fblogin.FaceBookAppKey %>',
                    status: true, // check login status
                    cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                    xfbml: true, // parse XFBML
                    oauth: true // enable OAuth 2.0
                });
            };
            (function () {
                var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
                e.src = document.location.protocol +
                '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
                document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
            } ());

            function loginByFacebook() {
                FB.login(function (response) {
                    if (response.authResponse) {
                        FacebookLoggedIn(response);
                    } else {
                        console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
                    }
                }, { scope: 'email' });
            }

            function FacebookLoggedIn(response) {
                var loc = '/fblogin.aspx';
                if (loc.indexOf('?') > -1)
                    window.location = loc + '&authprv=facebook&access_token=' + response.authResponse.accessToken;
                else
                    window.location = loc + '?authprv=facebook&access_token=' + response.authResponse.accessToken;
            }
        </script>


        </form>
namespace ecommerce
{
    public partial class fblogin : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public const string FaceBookAppKey = "xxxxxxxxxx";

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["access_token"])) return; //ERROR! No token returned from Facebook!!

            //let's send an http-request to facebook using the token            
            string json = GetFacebookUserJSON(Request.QueryString["access_token"]);

            //and Deserialize the JSON response
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            FacebookUser oUser = js.Deserialize<FacebookUser>(json);

            if (oUser != null)
            {
                Response.Write("Welcome, " + oUser.name);
                Response.Write("<br />id, " + oUser.id);
                Response.Write("<br />email, " + oUser.email);
                Response.Write("<br />first_name, " + oUser.first_name);
                Response.Write("<br />last_name, " + oUser.last_name);
                Response.Write("<br />gender, " + oUser.gender);
                Response.Write("<br />link, " + oUser.link);
                Response.Write("<br />updated_time, " + oUser.updated_time);
                Response.Write("<br />birthday, " + oUser.birthday);
                Response.Write("<br />locale, " + oUser.locale);
                Response.Write("<br />picture, " + oUser.picture);
                if (oUser.location != null)
                {
                    Response.Write("<br />locationid, " + oUser.location.id);
                    Response.Write("<br />location_name, " + oUser.location.name);
                }
            }
        }

        private static string GetFacebookUserJSON(string access_token)
        {
            string url = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token={0}&fields=email,name,first_name,last_name,link", access_token);

            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            Stream data = wc.OpenRead(url);
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
            string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
            data.Close();
            reader.Close();

            return s;
        }


        public class FacebookUser
        {
            public long id { get; set; }
            public string email { get; set; }

            public string name
            { get; set; }

            public string first_name
            { get; set; }

            public string last_name
            { get; set; }

            public string gender
            { get; set; }

            public string link
            { get; set; }

            public DateTime updated_time
            { get; set; }

            public DateTime birthday
            { get; set; }

            public string locale
            { get; set; }

            public string picture
            { get; set; }

            public FacebookLocation location
            { get; set; }
        }

        public class FacebookLocation
        {
            public string id
            { get; set; }

            public string name
            { get; set; }
        }

        static int a = 0;
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            a++;
            Label1.Text = Convert.ToString(a);
        }

    }
}
```

After added update panel my Facebook login function not working after the link is clicked.

I added AJAX page request manager. The post Back settings function it not work as what I expected.

After I remove added update panel works is working as I expect.

```
 /** This is what I try, but not work */
    function loginByFacebook() {

                var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
                if (prm != null) {
                    prm._postBackSettings(function (sender, e) {

                        if (sender.loginByFacebook.panelsToUpdate != null) {

                            loginByFacebook();


                        }

                    });
                };
            }
    */
```

Below is the screenshot issues i'm stuck.

Update panel events are rendered partially hence the events will looses.

[image: Login or Register Button]

After Login or Register Button is click. The Facebook login will not work as expected. The dialog box will not close automatically.

[image]

Comment: how can i bounty this question T_T